# How to handle deserialization of empty string into enum in json.net

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I am deserializing json properties into an enum but I'm having issues handling cases when the property is an empty string.

> Error converting value "" to type 'EnrollmentState'

I'm trying to deserialize the `state` property in a `requiredItem`.

```
{
    "currentStage" : "Pre-Approved",
    "stages" : ["Applicant", "Pre-Approved", "Approved", "Enrolled"],
    "requiredItems" : [{
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Documents",
            "state" : "" 
        }, {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "Eligibility Verification",
            "state" : "complete"
        }, {
            "id" : 3,
            "name" : "Placement Information",
            "state" : "incomplete"
        }
    ]
}
```

`RequiredItem` class and enum ...

```
public class RequiredItem {

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The identifier.</value>
    public string id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The name.</value>
    public string name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the status.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The status.</value>
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public EnrollmentState state { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum EnrollmentState {

    [EnumMember(Value = "incomplete")]
    Incomplete,

    [EnumMember(Value = "actionNeeded")]
    ActionNeeded,

    [EnumMember(Value = "complete")]
    Complete
}
```

How can I set a default value for the deserialization so that empty strings will be deserialized into `EnrollmentState.Incomplete` instead of throwing a runtime error?

Comment: Can you just add a handler for empty string to the EnrollmentState enum?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to implement custom `StringEnumConverter` if you want that:

```
public class EnrollmentStateEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.Value.ToString()))
            return EnrollmentState.Incomplete;

        return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(EnrollmentStateEnumConverter))]
public enum EnrollmentState
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "incomplete")]
    Incomplete,

    [EnumMember(Value = "actionNeeded")]
    ActionNeeded,

    [EnumMember(Value = "complete")]
    Complete
}
```

Comment: With NewtonSoft-6.0.5, enum deserialization is case insensitive. "incomplete" as json value will successfully deserialize to EnrollmentSate.Incomplete without any converter.
Serialization still is a problem.