# Enum as Required Field in ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it possible to return the `[Required]` attribute error message when a JSON request doesn't provide a proper value for an enum property?

For example, I have a model for a POST message that contains an `AddressType` property that is an enumeration type:

```
public class AddressPostViewModel
{
    [JsonProperty("addressType")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address type is required.")]
    public AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
}
```

The `AddressType` enum accepts two values:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum AddressType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Dropship")]
    Dropship,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Shipping")]
    Shipping
}
```

I've noticed (or actually my QA team noticed) that if the request message JSON contains either an empty string or null for the `AddressType`, the error message isn't the expected `Address type is required.` message. Instead, the error message is a somewhat unfriendly parsing error.

For example, if the request JSON looks like this:

```
{  "addressType": "" }
```

Then the error that is auto-generated by the validation framework looks like this:

```
{
    "message": "Validation Failed",
    "errors": [
        {
            "property": "addressType",
            "message": "Error converting value \"\" to type 'MyNamespace.AddressType'. Path 'addressType', line 4, position 19."
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to ensure that error message of the `[Required]` attribute is returned if someone doesn't include a valid value for an enum?

Comment: I'd say validation is working fine. An enum is a set of names on top of a base numeric type. They aren't nullable, so unless set, their value is the default value of their base type (ie 0). An empty string isn't a valid enum name. `null` isn't valid either, precisely because an enum isn't nullable.

Comment: If you want to "accept" missing values, the type would have to be nullable, ie `AddressType?`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I agree with you in that the validation is working correctly, it's just not what I want.  I do not wish to accept nulls or empty strings, I just want to present a user-friendly message if the client sends either of those values.

Comment: You could also use a validation package like FluentValidation for this specific case or all your validations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've come-up with a solution that meets my requirements, although the code makes me cringe a little.

I kept the `[Required]` attribute on the `AddressType` property in the view model.  The cringe-worthy part is that I had to make the property `nullable`:

```
public class AddressPostViewModel
{
    [JsonProperty("addressType")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address type is required.")]
    public AddressType? AddressType { get; set; }
}
```

On the `AttributeType` enum itself, I replaced the `StringEnumConverter` attribute with a custom `JsonConverter` as suggested by @Manoj Choudhari:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomStringToEnumConverter))]
public enum AddressType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Dropship")]
    Dropship,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Shipping")]
    Shipping
}
```

This is the `CustomStringToEnumConverter`:

```
public class CustomStringToEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.Value?.ToString()))
        {
            return null;
        }

        object parsedEnumValue;

        var isValidEnumValue = Enum.TryParse(objectType.GenericTypeArguments[0], reader.Value.ToString(), true, out parsedEnumValue);

        if (isValidEnumValue)
        {
            return parsedEnumValue;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The `CustomStringToEnumConverter` can handle empty strings, nulls, and invalid strings.  If it encounters an invalid enum value, it returns `null` which is then caught when the required field validation (magic) occurs and the `RequiredAttribute` error message is displayed in the JSON response.

While I don't like making the `AttributeType` type nullable, the consumer of my API will see a consistent validation message if the `AttributeType` value is wrong in the request JSON.

Comment: Thank you! Took me a couple of hours to analyze my problem, formulate a question and find your answer ;-)

Comment: Please reset the values of enum by setting first enum value to anything other than '0'. This will force system as default value '0' is not a valid enum

Comment: I got an error in this line 
var isValidEnumValue = Enum.TryParse(objectType.GenericTypeArguments[0], reader.Value.ToString(), true, out parsedEnumValue);

TryParse doesn't expect 4 params

Answer (score 10):

**Option 1: To use Custom RequiredEnum attribute and avoid JsonConverter attribute**

Do not put JsonConverter on the AddressType enum.  This StringToEnum is failing to map the string.Empty to enum value and it is throwing this error message.

Instead of that, you can write a custom required enum validator as shown below.

```
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public class RequiredEnumFieldAttribute: RequiredAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                 return false;
            }

            var type = value.GetType();
            return type.IsEnum && Enum.IsDefined(type, value);
        }
   }
```

Then you can use it like shown below:

```
public class AddressPostViewModel
{
    [JsonProperty("addressType")]
    [RequiredEnumField(ErrorMessage = "Address type is required.")]
    public AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
}
```

**Option 2: Use custom JsonConverter for AddressType**

Add one custom CustomStringToEnumConverter which is derived from StringEnumConverter.

This method would throw an error if the value in JSON is empty.

```
public class CustomStringToEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.Value.ToString()))
            throw new Exception("Address not provided");

        return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }
}
```

Use this jsonConverter instead of default StringEnumConverter as shown below

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomStringToEnumConverter))]
public enum AddressType
{
}
```

Comment: The custom required enum attribute code is only hit if I don't include the AddressType property in the JSON request at all.   If I set AddressType to an empty string or null, I get the same undesired "Error converting value" error.

Comment: +1, but if you throw the exception in the ReadJson method, the message in the required attribute still won't be displayed. OP should look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104575/how-to-handle-deserialization-of-empty-string-into-enum-in-json-net

Comment: @MikołajMularczyk - From the throw new exception we can throw the message which want to show on UI.   Another option is as you stated, we can map NULL or EMPTY string to some Enum value and then use custom attribute to throw error message.  But for that we will have to add a new value to Enum which will map to undefined.

Comment: You can have any message you want inside the exception, that is true, but unless OP has some middleware that catches and handles the exception, the consumer will get the internal server error (500).

Comment: Unfortunately, Option 1 does not work even when removing the StringEnumConverter attribute from the AddressType.  I still get the "Error converting value" exception.   Option 2 is looking a bit more promising as the custom converter code is getting triggered prior to the "Error converting value" error.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an out of the box data annotation validating enum values.

You can derive from the required attribute though:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public class RequiredEnumAttribute : RequiredAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null) return false;
            var type = value.GetType();
            return type.IsEnum && Enum.IsDefined(type, value);
        }
}
```

The `Enum.IsDefined` method is checking if a given `value` exists in the enum of given `type`.

Usage:

```
[RequiredEnum(ErrorMessage = "Your error message.")]
public YourEnum EnumProperty { get; set; }
```

See [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1062062/%2FTips%2F1062062%2FRequired-Enumeration-Validation-Attribute) article.

Comment: The custom required enum attribute code is only hit if I don't include the AddressType property in the JSON request at all.   If I set AddressType to an empty string or null, I get the same undesired "Error converting value" error.

Comment: Then your problem is with the JsonConverter, it is not able to parse an empty string. As @Manoj Chudari pointed out, you have to implement a custom one. You should look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104575/how-to-handle-deserialization-of-empty-string-into-enum-in-json-net

Answer (score 3):

(see the full write-up here: https://mtarleton.medium.com/enum-as-required-field-in-asp-net-core-webapi-a79b697ef270)

The problem faced here is the order of operations in converting the body to JSON and validating the model validations.

First, .NET de-serializes the body into JSON **with default values**. This means if you pass in a null value for a non-nullable ENUM the default value will be set for it (the first item in the ENUM usually). Same thing happens for primatives.

```cs
[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion in your article, but it doesn't work. If I omit the property from the JSON, I get no error. If I put an invalid enum value, I get an error from the JSON deserializer rather than the error message from the ValidEnumAttribute

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74410213) and [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/required-properties), .NET 7 introduced `[JsonRequired]` attribute which can validate whether the enum value was present in the JSON. It doesn't return the exact same error as `[Required]` attribute but the validation works none the less.

Answer (score 0):

Sample with overriding ValidationResult

```
 protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext? validationContext)
{
    var displayName = validationContext?.DisplayName ?? "";

    if (value == null)
    {
        return new ValidationResult($"{displayName} is required", new[] {displayName});
    }

    var type = value.GetType();
    if (type.IsEnum && Enum.IsDefined(type, value))
    {
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    return new ValidationResult($"Invalid value supplied for {displayName}", new[] {displayName});
}
```