# Is there any alternates Attribute for asp.net core enum model binding instead of EnumMemberAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

There's a enum type:

```cs
public enum Cat {
    [EnumMember(Value = "white_cat")]
    WhiteCat,
    [EnumMember(Value = "black_cat")]
    BlackCat
}
```

but use as follow asp.net core 2.2 model binding, it will binding failure:

```cs
public class A {
    public Cat TheCat { get; set; }
}

public class XXXController : ControllerBase {
    public ActionResult XXX([FromForm] Cat cat) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: "not work for asp.net core 2.2" - Could you please be more descriptive ? .Net Core do support EnumMember https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @AnuViswan edited. I know it's not work for asp.net core, so I ask any alternates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use enums with EnumMember attribute in FromBody ViewModel in Web API Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270237/how-to-use-enums-with-enummember-attribute-in-frombody-viewmodel-in-web-api-requ)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58338955/3907561

```cs
public class EnumMemberConverter<T> : EnumConverter {
    public EnumMemberConverter(Type type) : base(type) { }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
                                       CultureInfo culture, 
                                       object value) {
        var type = typeof(T);

        foreach (var field in type.GetFields()) {
            if (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(EnumMemberAttribute)) is EnumMemberAttribute attribute &&
                value is string enumValue &&
                attribute.Value == enumValue) {
                return field.GetValue(null);
            }
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

usage:

```cs
[TypeConverter(typeof(EnumMemberConverter<Cat>))]
public enum Cat {
    [EnumMember(Value = "white_cat")]
    WhiteCat,
    [EnumMember(Value = "black_cat")]
    BlackCat
}
```