# Deserialize object does not return full data in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, json.net

I have a JSON object that is coming back based on the keyword that the user type. It is returning only some of the typed keyword from the user. When I check postman and type the same keyword it returns properly.

The following exception is raised:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 
Must specify valid information for parsing in the string
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "valid": true,
  "result": {
    "points": [
      {
        "pointId": "505",
        "name": "Building one",
        "description": "Office of Technology and Data Application Development",
        "latitude": "xxx",
        "longitude": "xxx",
        "floor": "B",
        "aliases": [],
        "comments": [],
        "images": []
      }
    ],
    "categories": []
  },
  "errors": []
}
```

**Model classes**

```
public class SearchPoints
{
    public bool Valid { get; set; }
    public Result Result { get; set; }
    public List<string> Errors { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<Point> Points { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
  public long CategoryId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public long ParentId { get; set; }
  public string Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Point
{
    public long PointId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public Floor Floor { get; set; }
    public List<string> Aliases { get; set; }
    public List<string> Comments { get; set; }
    public List<string> Images { get; set; }
}

public enum Floor 
{ 
    A, 
    B 
};
```

**Service method**

```
var apiResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(Url + _keyword);
var apiContent = apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var pointsJsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchPoints>(apiContent);

var potentialPoints = new ObservableCollection<Point>(pointsJsonResponse.Result.Points);

PointsItemSource = potentialPoints;
```

Comment: have you compared the raw json returned in code vs. postman?  Are they the same or different?  If they are different then none of the code you posted is relevant to solving the problem.

Comment: Yes i compared them and they are the same.

Comment: so when you deserialize there are just some items missing?  How many?  Is there any pattern?

Comment: @Anthony How are you sending up the typed keyword?  As the user types or do they have a submit button to click?

Comment: Their is no number to how many is missing, i dont think there is a pattern. How i know some are missing is when i test the same keyword in postman i get the correct listing but when i test with the app i dont

Comment: @GaryStewart as the user types i am sending up the keyword and hitting the API

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with the TextChanged event ??

Comment: So what you are seeing are the results as the user types.  The requests are going up in an async manner and can return out of order.

Comment: @GaryStewart yes as the user types i am returning results from the API

Comment: @Anthony Exactly ... You are probably firing multiple calls to the API before the previous call(s) have returned.

Comment: @GaryStewart is there a way to limit that??

Comment: @GaryStewart i logged the error to App center as it returns 
`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Must specify valid information for parsing in the string`

Comment: Your answers are contradicting each other.  You said the raw responses from Postman and the app are identical.  Then later you say one returns a correct result and one doesn't - so obviously they aren't identical.

Comment: @Jason it is identical, when i debug it skip this line: `var potentialPoints = new ObservableCollection<Point>(pointsJsonResponse.Result.Points);`

Comment: The JSON in your question deserializes successfully, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/nDhNPL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON shown in your question deserializes successfully into the data model shown in your question, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/nDhNPL.

The exception shown in your question, however, provides some information.  The (somewhat opaque) message *Must specify valid information for parsing in the string* only appears **only once** in the Json.NET sources, according to a [search](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/search?q=Must+specify+valid+information+for+parsing+in+the+string.&unscoped_q=Must+specify+valid+information+for+parsing+in+the+string.), specifically in [`EnumUtils.ParseEnum(Type enumType, NamingStrategy? namingStrategy, string value, bool disallowNumber)`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/EnumUtils.cs#L287):

```
public static object ParseEnum(Type enumType, NamingStrategy? namingStrategy, string value, bool disallowNumber)
{

// SNIP

    if (firstNonWhitespaceIndex == -1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Must specify valid information for parsing in the string.");
    }
```

The relevant code is throwing an exception if, when parsing an `enum` string, the incoming value contains only whitespace.  So I modified the JSON in your question as follows:

```
    "floor": " ",
```

And reproduced the exception as shown here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6zaG9W.

Thus you must actually be attempting to parse JSON with an empty or whitespace value for `Floor` and failing because this is not possible.  To make this work, you could:

1. Change `Point.Floor` to be a string:

   ```
   public string Floor { get; set; }
   ```

   The JSON will now parse successfully.  Demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zg5YWr.
2. Use a special subclass of [`StringEnumConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm) that handles empty strings for `Floor`.  One example is shown in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20106359) to *[How to handle deserialization of empty string into enum in json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20104575)* by [Davor Zlotrg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622834/davor-zlotrg), which I generalize here:

   ```
   public class EmptyTolerantStringEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
   {
       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(reader.Value.ToString()))
               // Return a default value.  Note if deserializing a nullable enum the default value is null
               return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

           return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
       }       
   }
   ```

   And apply it as follows:

   ```
   [JsonConverter(typeof(EmptyTolerantStringEnumConverter))]
   public Floor Floor { get; set; }
   ```

   Or, if you prefer to map `""` to a nullable:

   ```
   [JsonConverter(typeof(EmptyTolerantStringEnumConverter))]
   public Floor? Floor { get; set; }
   ```

   Demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DwGKHU

Related: *[How to tell Json.Net globally to apply the StringEnumConverter to all enums](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7427909/3744182)* and *[parsing an enumeration in JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7799769/3744182)*.

Comment: Thank you, i knew i was parsing the JSON correctly but i didnt understand `EnumUtils.ParseEnum (System.Type enumType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.NamingStrategy namingStrategy, System.String value, System.Boolean disallowNumber)` error

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Json.Net cannot deserialize an 'object' type. It needs the real type:

So replace all your `List<object>` with `List<TRealType>`.

Example:

```
    public List<string> Aliases { get; set; }
    public List<string> Comments { get; set; }
    public List<string> Images { get; set; }
```

If you still get the error, then the error is in your `apiContent` variable which would not be a proper json string.

You also need to put the `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` attribute on your enum type.

Comment: It still doesnt seem to deserialize

Comment: Then your issue is in your `apiContent` string, so you need to update your post and add the code which creates this string.

Comment: Well your update is not good: you retrieve a apiResponse, and you deserialize a apiContent.

Comment: ok now put a breakpoint just after this line, and copy paste the value of apiContent in your post. And also update your post with all your SearchPoints, Result and Point classes with the changes you made on the List

Comment: the casing of your property names does not match the json

Comment: your property is "Valid" and the json is "valid" - Newtonsoft will not (I think) match those unless you specify a mapping attribute.  The same problem applies to all of the properties in your model.

Comment: This is what makes it tricky because it did pick up that keyword and showed it on the screen. To be clear it rendered that above JSON and showed it in a listview correctly

Comment: @Anthony update your initial post, please stop adding comments. Also update SearchPoints, Result and Point classes with the changes you made on the List

Comment: you didn't update your Model classes.. There are still some List<object> in it